# visibility binding does not work with tabitem

Tags: wpf

My view looks like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
   <TabControl  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
       <TabItem Header="TabItem1">
           <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Background="LightBlue" Visibility="{Binding Grid1Visiblity, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" IsVisibleChanged="Grid1_OnIsVisibleChanged"/>
       </TabItem>

       <TabItem Header="TabItem2" >
           <Grid Background="LightCyan" >
           </Grid>
       </TabItem>
   </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

and the code behind looks like

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Grid1Visiblity = true;
    }

    private Boolean grid1Visiblity;
    public Boolean Grid1Visiblity
    {
        get { return grid1Visiblity; }
        set
        {
            grid1Visiblity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Grid1Visiblity");
        }
    }
```

Now why is it that when I switch from TabItem1 to TabItem2 that I do not see Visiblity setter namely Grid1Visbility set?

I see that visibility changes when I use the IsVisibilityChanged event handler, from the MSDN docs the IsVisibilityChanged event is triggered only when visibility changes, so why does the binding does not work in my case.

Comment: the visibility of content panel gets changed not of the actual content. So perhaps using `SelectedItem` of tab control would be a better choice here

Comment: Did you try setting the `Visibility` on the `TabItem` instead of the `Grid`?

Comment: Hope you have already tried `Visibility="{Binding Path=Grid1Visiblity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"`